# Loss of quality on a tablet?

Tags: resolution, hdmi

I am about to buy a tablet with a screen resolution of 1280 x 800 ( 215 ppi ). I have a full HD monitor and I'd like to know what would happen if I connect the tablet to the monitor via HDMI and play a full HD movie. Is there any way to avoid losing quality?

Thanks for your answers.

Comment: Is the HDMI feed just a clone of the tablet screen?

Comment: I don't know. It depends on the app that's running the movie, right?

Comment: That depends on the tablet, which you've provided no information about.

Comment: OK it will be either a Nexus 7 (1st generation) or a Kobo Arc.